# How to track state of parent component from child component in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a page with photoalbums, and I need edit each album by click on the edit button in album component. I can't understand how to communicate between components if I have no common store(redux for example)
How to track  state of parent component from child component - Modal?

```js
var AlbumsPage = React.createClass({

 render: function ()
 {
  return(
    <div>
     <AlbumList url="Album/List"/>
    </div>
   );
 }
});


var AlbumList = React.createClass({

 componentDidMount: function ()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url: this.props.url,
   dataType: 'json',
   method: "POST",
   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
    this.setState({ data: data.Albums });
   }.bind(this),
   error: function (xhr, status, err) {
    console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
   }.bind(this)
  });
 },

 getInitialState: function()
 {
  return this.getAlbumListState();
  
 },

 getAlbumListState: function()
 {
  return {
   data: [],
   currentAlbum: null,
   showModal: false
  }
 },

 setCurrentAlbum: function(album){
  this.state.currentAlbum = album;
 },

 setShowModal : function(val){
  this.state.showModal = val;
 },

 getShowModal: function(){
  return this.state.showModal;
 },

 render: function () {

  var albums = this.state.data.map(function(album) { 
   return (
    <Album key={ album.Id } title={ album.Title } getShowModal={ this.getShowModal } setCurrentAlbum={ this.setCurrentAlbum }  setShowModal={ this.setShowModal }></Album>
     );
  }, this);
  

  return (
   <div>
    <div>
     { albums }
    </div>
    <AlbumModal showModal={ this.state.showModal } currentAlbum={ this.state.currentAlbum }/>
   </div>
  );
 }
});

var Album = React.createClass({

 open : function()
 {
  console.log("open fired");
  console.log(this.props.getShowModal());
  if (this.props.getShowModal()) {
   this.props.setShowModal(false);
   this.props.setCurrentAlbum(null);
  } else {
   this.props.setShowModal(true);
   this.props.setCurrentAlbum(this.props.album);
  }
 },

 render: function () {
  return (
    <div className="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
    <div className="thumbnail">
     <div className="caption">
      <h3>{ this.props.title }</h3>
      <p>
       <a onClick={ this.open }><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
       <a><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
 }
});


var AlbumModal = React.createClass({

 getInitialState: function() {
  
  return {

   showModal: this.props.showModal,
   currentAlbum: this.props.currentAlbum
  };
 },


 close: function() {
  this.setState({ showModal: false });
 },

 open: function() {
  this.setState({ showModal: true });
 },

 render: function() {
  return (
      <div>
        <ReactBootstrap.Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header closeButton>
            <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>Modal heading</ReactBootstrap.Modal.Title>
          </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Header>
          <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
            <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
          </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Body>
          <ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
            <ReactBootstrap.Button onClick={this.close}>Close</ReactBootstrap.Button>
          </ReactBootstrap.Modal.Footer>
        </ReactBootstrap.Modal>
      </div>
      )
}
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <AlbumsPage />,
  document.getElementById('albums')
);
```

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example of the question. Too much going on here and it's unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to pass the parent as a prop to the child component.

So in your `AlbumList::render`, you'd have to do

    `return (
        <Album
            key={ album.Id }
            title={ album.Title }
            getShowModal={ this.getShowModal }
            setCurrentAlbum={ this.setCurrentAlbum }
            setShowModal={ this.setShowModal }
            parent={this}
        >
      </Album>
    );`

But this will create a huge overhead once you start passing states to many different components.

A good plugin to solve this would be to use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/)

Comment: @Diego_Fu It seems that you are right, I try don't use redux because my application isn't a SPA, but I think reactjs without redux -  it is wrong way! Thank you so much.